# PL/SQL Error PLS-00103 - Encountered symbol xxxx when expecting yyyy

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know these errors are most often caused by typos; that's what I've been finding at least. If my problem is a typo, I cannot see it after ~30 minutes of looking, it's driving me crazy.

My question is: am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or can you see a typo?

PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Replenish_Stock(p_id  VARCHAR2, n  INT)
AS
  no_such_id EXCEPTION;
  CURSOR pc IS
    SELECT Product_ID FROM Products;

BEGIN
  IF p_id IN pc THEN
    UPDATE Products
    SET Stock_Level = Stock_Level + n
    WHERE product_id = p_id;
  ELSE
    RAISE no_such_id;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad integer input, ignoring procedure call.');
    WHEN no_such_id THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad Product id, ignoring procedure call.');
END;
/
```

Error code:

```
Error(7,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PC" when expecting one of the following:     (
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of IN and CURSOR is not right. the below should work for you. You can just use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to see if the update query impact any rows in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Replenish_Stock(p_id  VARCHAR2, n  INT)
AS
   no_such_id EXCEPTION;
   Rows_Updated NUMBER;

BEGIN

    UPDATE Products
    SET Stock_Level = Stock_Level + n
    WHERE product_id = p_id;


  IF( SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
    RAISE no_such_id;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad integer input, ignoring procedure call.');
    WHEN no_such_id THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad Product id, ignoring procedure call.');
END;
/
```